# X-UA-Compatible=IE8 and doctype make IE8 search function extremely slow on larger tables

Tags: performance, search, internet-explorer-8, doctype, x-ua-compatible

I noticed that when you have a rather large table (few thousand rows), the IE8 search function (Ctrl+F) becomes extremely slow when you use the doctype and set X-UA-Compatible to IE=8:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
        ...
```

Currently we have no way to decrease the size of the tables. Also, removing or changing the doctype or X-UA-Compatible messes up the layout of the page, so that's no quick solution either.

Does anyhave have any other ideas how to make the IE8 search function quicker?

To show the difference I created two test files that you can try (in IE8):

- http://playground.steven.comprise.com/ie8/fast.php
- http://playground.steven.comprise.com/ie8/slow.php

fast.php is the one without doctype or X-UA-Compatible. In this file the search is fast!
slow.php uses both the doctype and the X-UA-Compatible, so we want search in this file to become equally fast as in fast.php

Ideas?

Comment: We ended up showing a message to IE8 users, warning them that search is slow, and that they should use IE>8 or a different browser for that. Not ideal, but absolutely acceptable for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own search dialog (shown when ctrl+f is pressed). But I think it won't be faster than in IE8 compatibility mode. The reason the search in IE>8 is faster is that it uses newer DOM & JavaScript engine.